# PHP not running for FOG web management server

Tags: apache2, php, fog

I am making an imaging server for my computer engineering course.

I have installed Ubuntu Server 12.04 32-bit on the dual processor server, then I upgraded using d-release-upgrade to 14.04.

I then tried to install the fog imaging tools using the provided `installfog.sh` script. I had already successfully completed the install on a different computer (Ubuntu desktop 14.04 64-bit). After installing onto the desktop you could access the web tools by accessing /fog/management on a web browser. On the desktop the page rendered completely fine.

The last step of installing fog asks you to update the mysql database (IIRC) by logging into the website. Whereas the desktop worked fine, the server does not. Yesterday, when trying to access the website, it would instantly ask you to download a file, as if it were a download link. The file was always a random set of letters capital and lowercase with no file extension. When opened the file was a PHP file. When I looked in htop for any PHP process I could not find one.

This morning, I `sudo apt-get purge` 'd php5 and a few other php5 packages that the fog install log said it installed, then I reinstalled them. After starting the FOG installation again, I once again came to the last step. This time instead of prompting for a download, it appeared to display a "half-rendered" webpage, with the default FOG blue background and FOG logo, but also with random strings of (what I assume is) PHP code simply strewn around the screen.

I really need this problem fixed but I have never done web server things before. I have totally stumped my instructor in the process.

Comment: Can you provide more info? Logs, screenshots, and the installfog.sh script will be very helpful.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the issue...  http://i.imgur.com/e8iP38z.png

Comment: Can you, please, provide the exit of this command: "sudo apache2ctl -M | sort" Remember to remove the quotes, please.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/EeuhyK7v

Answer (score 1):

Using the provided information as a base, you don't have PHP installed to run with Apache (as an Apache module). The common installation is to use PHP as a module of Apache, what can be easily be achieved using apt-get like this:

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
sudo service apache2 restart
```

This should solve your problem.